# Creating data frame with incremental minutes as rows (R)

Tags: r

I would like to create a data frame that will look like this:

```
Date          Time   
-------      ------- 
02/01/2016    14:00
02/01/2016    14:01 
02/01/2016    14:02
```

I have a dataset that starts on 02/01/2016 at 14:00, but I just need it to start there, and create empty rows for the minutes between where the dataset has timestamped data and where it doesn't. For context, this is what the timestamped dataset looks like:

```
cost    date       time
-----  -----       -----
$300   02/01/2016   14:00 
$120   02/01/2016   14:03
```

I want my end resulting data frame to look something like this:

```
Date          Time     Cost
-------      -------  ------
02/01/2016    14:00   $300
02/01/2016    14:01    
02/01/2016    14:02 
02/01/2016    14:03   $120
02/01/2016    14:04
```

Thank you!

Comment: Does your data set span a single day (`02/01/2016`) or does it span multiple days?

Comment: The dataset spans multiple days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the function seq.POSIXt.  This function is designed to create sequences of time.  For your problem:

```
seq(ISOdate(2016,2,02, 14, 00, 00), by = "min", length.out = 5)
```

There are options to specify the start and stop intervals.  If you are going to be working much with times, I suggest researching the function strptime and the POSIXt time class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution that should get you started. It uses `lubridate` and `dplyr`.  It also combines `date` and `time` and converts to a `POSIXct` object.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
ts_seqdf <- data.frame(date_time = seq(mdy_hm('02/01/2016 14:00'),
                                       mdy_hm('02/01/2016 14:04'),
                                       by = '1 min'))
datadf %>%
    mutate(date_time = mdy_hm(paste(date, time, sep = ' '))) %>%
    right_join(ts_seqdf, by = 'date_time') %>%
    select(-date, -time)

##   cost           date_time
## 1  300 2016-02-01 14:00:00
## 2   NA 2016-02-01 14:01:00
## 3   NA 2016-02-01 14:02:00
## 4  120 2016-02-01 14:03:00
## 5   NA 2016-02-01 14:04:00
```

Input data:

```
datadf <- structure(list(cost = c(300L, 120L), date = c("02/01/2016", "02/01/2016"), time = c("14:00", "14:03")), .Names = c("cost", "date", "time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```